# How is this character alive in season 5 of "The Flash"?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In season 5 episode 8 we discover that:

> XS is working in the future (2049) with Eobard Thawne, however Eobard was erased from existence in season 1 and then again captured by the time ghosts after his appearance on *Legends of Tomorrow*. I had thought we was definitely gone, specially since Eddie Thawne remains dead and gone.

So how is he alive? Did I miss something?

Comment: Altered universes.

Comment: *Wait and see*. That's the big mystery of the season. We will probably learn about it in incoming episodes. If I am not wrong, Word of God said it is the same character as the one we saw in the crossover with the Nazi universe.

Comment: Infinite number of time remnants...

Comment: In addition to the "time remnant" theory, he could simply be an earlier Thawne.

Comment: I found an explanation on google, whether it's a satisfactory explanation is up to you- an article called the Flash Timeline Explained- https://ca.ign.com